# Problem with adding elements from functions to list (too much memory is using?)

Tags: python, recursion, memoization

I replace in this code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#parametry dla romeo i julii, zeby byly niezmienne w uczuciach musza byc wieksze od 0
aR = 0.5
aL = 0.7
#pR pL odpowiedzi Romea/Julii na miłość
pR = 0.2
pL = 0.5
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]
rom = []
jul = []

def Romeo(n):
    if n == 0:
         return 1
    return Romeo(n - 1)*aR

def Julia(n):
    if n == 0:
         return 1
    return Julia(n - 1)*aL

def alfa(n):
    if n == 0:
         return 1
    return aR*Romeo(n - 1) + pR*Julia(n - 1)

def beta(n):
    if n == 0:
         return 1
    return aL*Julia(n - 1) + pL*Romeo(n - 1)


j = 0
while j < 100:
    rom.append(alfa(j))
    j+=1

j = 0
while j < 100:
    jul.append(beta(j))
    j+=1

plt.plot(x, rom, label = "Romeo love")
plt.plot(x, jul, label = "Julia love")


plt.xlabel("Days")
plt.ylabel("Romeo love")
plt.title("Some graph")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

only alfa and beta functions byt this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#parametry dla romeo i julii, zeby byly niezmienne w uczuciach musza byc wieksze od 0
aR = 0.5
aL = 0.7
#pR pL odpowiedzi Romea/Julii na miłość
pR = 0.2
pL = 0.5
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, ]
rom = []
jul = []

def Romeo(n):
    if n == 0:
         return 1
    return Romeo(n - 1)*aR

def Julia(n):
    if n == 0:
         return 1
    return Julia(n - 1)*aL

def alfa(n):
    if n == 0:
         return 1
    return round(aR*alfa(n - 1) + pR*beta(n - 1), 3)

def beta(n):
    if n == 0:
         return 1
    return round(aL*beta(n-1) + pL*alfa(n - 1), 3)


j = 0
while j < 100:
    rom.append(alfa(j))
    j+=1

j = 0
while j < 100:
    jul.append(beta(j))
    j+=1

plt.plot(x, rom, label = "Romeo love")
plt.plot(x, jul, label = "Julia love")


plt.xlabel("Days")
plt.ylabel("Romeo love")
plt.title("Some graph")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

And Pycharm does not want to compilate (does not draw this graph) or it will take a lot of time. Ealier it was not a problem. \
I thought that a lot of numbers after point can be a reason and i round every number from list, but it didnt solve the problem.

What I changed by replacing this functions? How can I fix that?

Im pretty sure that the problem is in assigning elements from functions to list [2 while]. But i do not know why.

Answer (score 0):

The current recursive approach is wasteful.

- For example, when computing `alfa(1)` would require `alfa(0)`, `beta(0)`.
- When you move on to `alfa(2)`, the code will first compute `alfa(1)` and `beta(1)`. Then `alfa(1)` would call `alfa(0)` and `beta(0)`, while `beta(1)` would separately call `alfa(0)`, `beta(0)` **again**, without recycling what we have computed before. So you need 6 calls for `alfa(2)`.
- At `alfa(3)`, you would compute `alfa(2)` and `beta(2)`, each of which needs 6 calls; so you need 14 calls (if my math is not off).
- Imagine how many computations you would need at `n == 100`; the answer is 2535301200456458802993406410750. Cumulatively, i.e., since you want to plot `alfa(1)`, ..., `alfa(100)`, you need 5070602400912917605986812821300
  computations in total, only to produce a single list `rom`.

You can use [*memoization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) to remember the previously calculated results and recycle them.

In python, you can achieve this by using `functools.lru_cache` ([python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache)); put

```py
from functools import lru_cache
```

at the beginning of your code and then put

```py
@lru_cache()
```

before each function; e.g.,

```py
@lru_cache()
def Romeo(n):
    if n == 0:
         return 1
    return Romeo(n - 1)*aR
```

You will see the graph almost immediately now.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! :)